# Got an Error The contract function "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED

Tags: bep20, pancakeswap, cryptotokenkit

I encountered an error while trying to add liquidity to a pool on pancakeswap. The error message I received was:

"Add liquidity failed: Unknown error: "The contract function "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED". Try increasing your slippage tolerance."

I'm not sure what caused this error or how to resolve it. I've tried increasing my slippage tolerance, ensuring sufficient token allowance, and checking my token balance, but the issue persists.

Has anyone else encountered this error before? If so, what steps did you take to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!